# Details on MS Teams meeting using Azure logic app

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps

There is a scenario in my company wherein Azure Logic App has initiated a MS Teams meeting and we have added required members into that meeting. If somehow we missed to add additional members into MS Teams meeting via Logic App then how can we add those additional members into an existing MS Teams meeting via Logic App?

Comment: Hi, may I know if the solution helps your requirement ?

Comment: @Hury Shen - Yes, this will help. Also one more question I am having. I have created a logic App wherein it will create MS Teams then will add members in it then it will create a channel and will post message into it. Now after that what I want is, it should start Teams call immediately using same MS teams which got created my logic app.

Comment: As per my analysis so far I found a connector wherein I can schedule MS Teams meeting but this is altogether a different Teams which will be created. What I want is when I create MS Teams then I will add members and will create channel then after that it should immediately start a call with all the members added into Teams.

Is this possible?

Comment: Hi, I will do some more research and come back if find the solution.

Comment: Hi, I noticed that you have created another new [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/67623521/how-to-initiate-a-ms-teams-call-using-logic-app) for your further question. Could you please accept my answer in current post and I will work on your new post. If I find solution, I will post the answer under your new post.

Comment: @Hury Shen - Yes, sure and thanks a lot for your help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Currently there isn't a connector/action for us to add members to an existing meeting in logic app. But if you can update the meeting by [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/onlinemeeting-update?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) graph api.

You can use the graph api to update the meeting, of course update the members of meeting. To implement it, you need to register an app in your AD first and add the permission to it.

[image]

Then in logic app, you need to use "HTTP" action to request for access token, do it like below screenshot:

[image]

The response of "HTTP" action will response the access token, then parse the response of "HTTP" action and get the access token. Add another "HTTP" action to request the graph api above and set the access token in request headers.