# How to initiate a MS Teams call using logic app

Tags: microsoft-teams, azure-logic-apps, microsoft-graph-teams

I have created a logic App wherein it will create MS Teams, will add members in it then it will create a channel and will post message into it. Now after that what I want is, it should start Teams call immediately using same MS teams which got created by logic app.

As per my analysis so far I found a connector wherein I can schedule MS Teams meeting but this is altogether a different Teams which will be created. What I want is when I create MS Teams then I will add members and will create channel. After that it should immediately start a call with all the members added into Teams. Is this possible?

Comment: It seems there isn't a connector or action for us to start the call directly in logic app. Do you mind request this [api](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) to create the call ?

Answer (score 0):

There is no MS Graph endpoint to create a meeting in a teams channel. You can create a feature request [here](https://microsoftteams.uservoice.com/forums/908686-bug-reports).

An option you can try is to use [Cloud Communication Create onlineMeeting](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-onlinemeetings?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) using an attendee list synthesized from the [list for channel members](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/channel-list-members?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http). Note you will have to do the meeting on behalf of one member of the channel, the rest as attendees and post the meeting info to that channel.

Answer (score 0):

Create a calling and meeting bot, After creating a channel you can add the bot to the channel when you add the bot to channel you will receive the [installation event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#install-update-event)/[conversation update event](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/microsoftteams/platform/bots/how-to/conversations/subscribe-to-conversation-events?tabs=dotnet#conversation-update-events) in the logic and there you can call the [create call API](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http) and start a call with the members added to the team using [Create a group call with service hosted media](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/application-post-calls?view=graph-rest-1.0&tabs=http#example-3-create-a-group-call-with-service-hosted-media)

Comment: I believe calling and meeting bot option is not available in azure logic app.

Comment: It does not require a calling bot you will receive the conversation update event for normal bot also, you can call graph API when you receive an event, you need to add the required permissions to your application to call graph API